# How to get same fields in POST

Tags: php

```
<form action="form.php" id="form">
<input type="text" name="name_1"><input type="text" name="city_1"><input type="text" name="country_1">
<input type="text" name="name_2"><input type="text" name="city_2"><input type="text" name="country_2">
<input type="text" name="name_3"><input type="text" name="city_3"><input type="text" name="country_3">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How is the best method for get this data in form.php file? This is generated with jQuery. Can be 3 (as now) or 30.

In form.php i have:

```
$data = new Data();
$data->name = $_POST['name_1'];
$data->city = $_POST['city_1'];
$data->country = $_POST['country_1'];
$data->save();
$data = new Data();
$data->name = $_POST['name_2'];
$data->city = $_POST['city_2'];
$data->country = $_POST['country_2'];
$data->save();
$data = new Data();
$data->name = $_POST['name_3'];
$data->city = $_POST['city_3'];
$data->country = $_POST['country_3'];
$data->save();
```

But if there is over 3? I would like use **foreach**, but how? How can i generated input or get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the names of the input elements you could do it like that:

```
<input type="text" name="items[1][name]"><input type="text" name="items[1][city]"><input type="text" name="items[1][country]">
<input type="text" name="items[2][name]"><input type="text" name="items[2][city]"><input type="text" name="items[2][country]">
<input type="text" name="items[3][name]"><input type="text" name="items[3][city]"><input type="text" name="items[3][country]">
```

The numbers don't have to be adjacent but the have to be unique. To convert the `$_POST`-data to your data-model would then look like that:

```
$items = $_POST['items'];

$dataList = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
    $data = new Data();
    $data->name = $item['name'];
    $data->city = $item['city'];
    $data->country = $item['country'];
    $dataList[] = $data;
}
```

Of course you can add as many items as you want.

If you can't change the names of the input elements then you could use one of the other solutions. I would only modify them so that the number of elements is not hard coded like:

```
$dataList = array()
for($i = 1; isset($_POST["name_$i"]); ++$i) {
    $data = new Data();
    $data->name = $_POST["name_$i"];
    // ... and so on
    $dataList[] = $data;
}
```

Of course, with that solution the numbers must be continuous/adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

Use `name[]`, `city[]` and `country[]` as your input names. Then they'll come through to PHP as arrays which you can iterate with `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
  $data = new Data();
  $data->name = $_POST['name_'.$i];
  $data->city = $_POST['city_'.$i];
  $data->country = $_POST['country_'.$i];
  $data->save();
}
```

But if you could change your html like:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]"><input type="text" name="city[]"><input type="text" name="country[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]"><input type="text" name="city[]"><input type="text" name="country[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]"><input type="text" name="city[]"><input type="text" name="country[]">
```

You will not need to know the count.(`name_1,name_2` would be better to be the id but not name)

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $index => $name) {
  $data = new Data();
  $data->name = $name;
  $data->city = $_POST['city'][$index];
  $data->country = $_POST['country'][$index];
  $data->save();
}
```

Comment: @Esailija Yes, If he known that would be 3, or change his html would be better.

Comment: I was commenting your initial post, which had hardcoded it to be 3 sets of values, when the original question wanted to handle a case where there is variable amount, for example over 3.

Comment: @Esailija Yes, `3` is just an example, if he can not change the html, he need to figure out `3` by program.

Comment: this is good example, but if form have errors, then if i show him again then i can't assign data to appropriate fields in form and i must again fill in this

Answer (score 0):

You can use your for each with on time built strings like 'name_.$i', with $i as a counter